# How to install my app on other's iphone/ipod touch device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-developer-program

I created new IPhone app, created all the development provisioning profile and AdHoc distribution profile, and I uploaded that app on my local server with .plist, .ipa and .html. this html looks like below:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.myServer. ocm/myApp/myApp.plist">Install My App</a>
```

This html file is hosted at http://www.myServer. ocm/myApp/myApp.html

I typed the above URL and got that html page and clicked "Install My App" and It installs myApp on my device. But When I am trying this step on other's device It is not installed.

And after sometime later, I just deleted the Team Provisioning profile from my device and tried the same, but the app is not installed on my device..

I am frustrated about the provisioning profiles and Team provisioning profile.
What is this Team proviso
Is any relation with Team provisioning profile?
How this Team provisioning profile is created?
and

Answer (score 0):

You must register the device in Xcode on your dev machine, or publish your app on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Your App contains a provisioning profile, in your case the team provisioning profile when you did not create on specially for this app.

To run the app on a device the provisioning profile must contain the udid of that device.

you can unzip the ipa and open the "embedded.mobileprovision" file. There you find a list of all devices that are allowed to run the app that looks like:

```
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
<array>
    <string>a8c7a34f7f9ed2e8f27XXXXX552eb3b0357c986e</string>
    <string>c59a32XXXXX41659b04f50b71bf807e3274a72b2</string>
    <string>053fb019116fb65944ba8918df793XXXXX3e5b02</string>
</array>
```

Only those devices are allowed to run the app.. and to allow other devices you have to add them to the provisioning profile using xcode or the developer portal before you compile and upload the app.

Answer (score 0):

First off, are you using the Team Provisioning Profile that is managed by Xcode? You will need to create an ad hoc distribution provisioning profile on the Apple Developer Portal to create an ad hoc. Instructions on creating this profile are on the developer site. It sounds like you are using a development profile instead of an ad hoc distribution profile.

In order to include a device in the provisioning profile you do not need to set it up via Xcode. I assume you hooked your device up, opened Organizer, and clicked Use For Development? This just sets the device up so you can install your application directly onto your device.

1. You need all the UDID's of other devices for which allow your app to install.
2. Now Go to the Provisioning Portal and add those device (UDID's) to the list, if this has not already been done.
3. Create an Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile. When creating this you can select which devices you would like your app to run on. When this is complete you should see the profile count increase on the devices section of the Portal.
4. Download this new profile and build your app using these instructions on creating an IPA for ad hoc distribution: [How to create an IPA (Xcode 4)](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4)
5. Upload the app executable and IPA file.

I would recommend to use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/), a very interesting project with a simple goal: to make distributing and installing beta versions of apps as simple as tapping a button.

Good luck!